# has_many belongs_to association with a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, associations

Let's say you have two models `Venue` and `Photo`. Each `Venue` can have many `Photos`, but it can only have *one* `FeaturedPhoto`. Each `Photo` can be belong to many `Venues` and can be the `FeaturedPhoto` of more than one Venue too.

I already have the general has_and_belongs_to_many relationship set up and working through a join table with these models:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
  has_and_belongs_to_many :venues
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
end
```

To add the FeaturedPhoto, it seems like I would need to add a column called featured_photo_id to the Venue model and then set up a has_many, belongs_to association between the two. But I'm not sure where to add the foreign_key info. Is this right?

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
  has_and_belongs_to_many :venues
  has_many :venues
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :photos
  belongs_to :photo, foreign_key: "featured_photo_id", class_name: "Photo"
end
```

Or do I have to add foreign_key info to both models?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved if you add a model for intermediate table PhotosVenue and add a boolean column is_featured in this intermediate table.

I created a demo app to do exactly what you want. Check this [github repo](https://github.com/himesh-r/Photos_demo)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[**has_many :through**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

I concur with `SiriusROR` - you need to use a `has_many :through` model, with an extra boolean attribute called `featured`:

```
#app/models/photo.rb
Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photo_venues
   has_many :venues, through: :venue_photos
end

#app/models/venue.rb
Class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photo_venues
   has_many :photos, through: :venue_photos do
       def featured
           find_by featured: true
       end
   end
end

#app/models/photo_venue.rb
Class VenuePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :photo
   belongs_to :venue
end
```

--

Your schema for the `:through` model should be set up like this:

```
#photo_venues
id | photo_id | venue_id | featured | created_at | updated_at
```

--

This will allow you to call:

```
@venue.photos.featured # -> should bring back the single ActiveRecord object for the first featured photo in the collection
```